# Galois group of tamely ramified extension of local field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Suppose $L/K$ is a (finite) tamely ramified extension of local fields. What can be said about $\text{Gal}(L/K)$? For instance, is it true that $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ is the  semidirect product of $I$ (the inertia subgroup, which we note is cyclic in this case) and $\text{Gal}(k_L/k_K)$?

I believe this is the case if $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$, where we can use Schur-Zassenhaus to the exact sequence $1\to I\to \text{Gal}(L/K)\to \text{Gal}(k_L/k_K)\to1$.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not a semi-direct product. Even over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Counter-example: [This field](https://www.lmfdb.org/padicField/7.9.6.3) of degree $9$ over $\mathbb{Q}_7$ has a cyclic Galois group, but it is obtained as an unramified cubic extension, followed by a tamely ramified cubic extension.

If the ramification index $e$ is coprime to the residue class degree $f$, then Schur-Zassenhaus implies that the Galois group is semi-direct.